# Azure function with Python V2 - How to use custom modules

Tags: python, azure-functions

Is there a way to use modules from outside of the function_app.py?

In v1 I had a folder shared_code that I imported at the begining.

```
function app
- shared_code
  - __init__.py
  - helper_function.py
- function_app.py
```

`from shared_code import  helper_functions`

I created a v2 function now, the template worked fine. Then I created the shared_code folder, still working. Then I used it in my function_app.py.
Now the function is gone, not reachable and in Azure Portal it disapeared.

Any thoughts, how I can use this?
As I understood, blueprints are not meant for this, right?

Comment: Can you share your helper_function and function_app.py?

Answer (score 0):

I have created http trigger function with runtime stack python and added custom modules in the project directory.

**folder structure:**

[image]

**helper_function:**

```
def  greet(name):
return  f"Hello, {name}!"
```

**function_app code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
from shared_code import helper_functions
import datetime
import json
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        value=helper_functions.greet(name)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {value}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

I can call the helper function in the function_app and import the function like `from shared_code import helper_functions`.
The above function executed successfully. check below:

[image]

[image]

The above function deployed successfully into azure portal. check the status below:

[image]
[image]

The function executed successfully in azure portal as well. check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is weird. Did the same and the function just disapeared... Have to check all details then. Thanks for assuring it should work